# BackgroundGeolocation with Angular 9 and Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova

I try to add the @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation plugin into my Angular9 + Cordova Project (not Ionic).
I installed the Cordova Plugin and the NPM Plugin.
I added the Plugin into my Project with

```
import {BackgroundGeolocationPlugin} from '@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation';
```

now I just tried to get it to work with the following in my Main.ts

```
const bootstrap = () => {
  console.log("Platform is Android or IOS")
      var backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocationPlugin;
      backgroundGeolocation.configure({
      locationProvider: backgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
      desiredAccuracy: backgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
      stationaryRadius: 5,
      distanceFilter: 5,
      notificationTitle: 'SOF-Background Location',
      notificationText: 'enabled',
      debug: true,
      interval: 60000,
      fastestInterval: 10000,
      activitiesInterval: 10000,
      url: 'http://192.168.81.15:3000/location',
      // customize post properties
      postTemplate: {
        lat: '@latitude',
        lon: '@longitude',
      }
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('location', function(location) {
      console.log(location)
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log('[ERROR] BackgroundGeolocation error:', error.code, error.message);
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('start', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service has been started');
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('stop', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service has been stopped');
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('authorization', function(status) {
      console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation authorization status: ' + status);
      if (status !== backgroundGeolocation.AUTHORIZED) {
        // we need to set delay or otherwise alert may not be shown
        setTimeout(function() {
          var showSettings = confirm('App requires location tracking permission. Would you like to open app settings?');
          if (showSettings) {
            return backgroundGeolocation.showAppSettings();
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('background', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] App is in background');
      // you can also reconfigure service (changes will be applied immediately)
      backgroundGeolocation.configure({ debug: true });
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('foreground', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] App is in foreground');
      backgroundGeolocation.configure({ debug: false });
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('abort_requested', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] Server responded with 285 Updates Not Required');

      // Here we can decide whether we want stop the updates or not.
      // If you've configured the server to return 285, then it means the server does not require further update.
      // So the normal thing to do here would be to `BackgroundGeolocation.stop()`.
      // But you might be counting on it to receive location updates in the UI, so you could just reconfigure and set `url` to null.
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.on('http_authorization', () => {
      console.log('[INFO] App needs to authorize the http requests');
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(function(status) {
      console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service is running', status.isRunning);
      console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation services enabled', status.locationServicesEnabled);
      console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation auth status: ' + status.authorization);

      // you don't need to check status before start (this is just the example)
      if (!status.isRunning) {
        backgroundGeolocation.start(); //triggers start on start event
      }
    });

    // you can also just start without checking for status
    // BackgroundGeolocation.start();

    // Don't forget to remove listeners at some point!
    // BackgroundGeolocation.removeAllListeners();
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};

if (typeof window["cordova"] !== "undefined") {
  document.addEventListener(
    "deviceready",
    () => {
      bootstrap();
    },
    false
  );
} else {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

But every time I try to start the Android App I get the following Console Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined
    at bootstrap (main.ts:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code as of now you are only defining the backgroundGeolocation as type

```
var backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocationPlugin;
```

This is what causes the error in your case.

For Angular, it is common to do dependency injection at a class constructor that "cares" about geolocation.

Ideally, you want to use a framework that was made to work with Cordova, but in this use case (Angular + Cordova), you should try to access the Plugin you are importing via the global window object property after the listener confirmed device is ready:

```
if (BackgroundGeolocationPlugin in window) {
    var backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocationPlugin = window.BackgroundGeolocationPlugin;
}
```

Comment: When I try it, I get the error "'BackgroundGeolocationPlugin' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." And when I try to put it into a component's constructor I get "No suitable injection token for parameter 'backgroundGeolocation' of class 'LocationService'."

Comment: OK can you share how did you import Cordova plugin in first place? app.module.ts?

Comment: Not in the app.module.ts, there I get the same error. It should work when I import it like an external Javascript Libary (import * as BackgroundGeolocation from ',,,') But then I get errors too (The BackgroundGeolocation .js has some required fields which he doesn't find)

Comment: which guide did you follow to wrap your app into cordova?

Comment: Do you mean to wrap my Angular App into Cordova in general? https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79 That would be this one. Everything up to the service. I probably have to implement the Cordova service and stuff too...

Comment: Try accessing the plugin in your app via the window object in your case.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is probably not want you wanna here, but this Plugin is not working correctly. There is currently one working Plugin for Background Geolocation, which is working perfect and is daily tested and maintained, but it is not free. In our Team we decided to bough it as we need this Feature.

> https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

Comment: I have the headache with this plugin, undefined... when it comes to work with hardware, mobile app with Cordova in general is a bad idea

Comment: This is a commercial plugin promoted.